# PHP: $_SESSION variable echo giving mixed results

Tags: php, session

Please help me out, I am running into a very strange problem.

```
<?php
if($_SESSION['checkout_betaling'] == 'ideal') { $betaling = 'Betaling direct per iDeal.'; }
elseif($_SESSION['checkout_betaling'] == 'overschrijving') { $betaling = 'Betaling door handmatige overschrijving.'; }
else { $betaling = 'Goederen geleverd op rekening.'; }
?>
```

When I echo `$_SESSION['checkout_betaling']` it outputs "**ideal**".

But when I echo `$betaling` it outputs "**Goederen geleverd op rekening**".

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `var_dump($_SESSION['checkout_betaling']);` check for extra spaces etc

Comment: Check spaces for example: 'ideal ' (space at the end) would not go into the if statement, it will go into the else statement. Same for any variation

Comment: "var_dump($_SESSION['checkout_betaling']);" gives **string(5) "Ideal"**

Comment: so it echoed "ideal" but var_dumped "Ideal" i somehow doubt that

Comment: i or I, succes is in the details

Comment: If you got the value "Ideal" (in upper case ) that's mean "Ideal" (in upper case) passed to the SESSION. Just explore code where you write data to  the $_SESSION

Answer (score 0):

OK, Got the answer,

`var_dump($_SESSION['checkout_betaling']);` gives **string(5) "Ideal"**

I had hidden a `ucfirst()` when creating the variable....

Comment: Your question was caused by an issue that could not be reproduced by volunteers.  It is not likely to gain upvotes and may gain downvotes. This page will offer little value to future readers and may be deleted.  You may delete your own answer and question if you wish -- this will spare volunteers having to close it and then delete it for you.